# How to get number of phy / logical cores?

Tags: command-line, coreutils

There are a lot of questions about number of cores, [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481005/how-to-obtain-the-number-of-cpus-cores-in-linux-from-the-command-line) , but none give the correct logical cores AFAIK.

The best thing I can think of, is calculating myself using the following formulas:

```
Physical cores = <Cores per socket> * <sockets>
Logical cores = <Threads per core> * Physical cores
```

which I can get by:

```
threads=$(lscpu | awk '/^Thread/{print $NF}')
cores=$(lscpu | awk '/^Core\(/{print $NF}')
sockets=$(lscpu | awk '/^Socket/{print $NF}')
phy=$(( $sockets * $cores ))
logi=$(( $phy * $threads ))
```

Is there a better way?

EDIT:

- Based on generic utils, i.e. without installing new pkgs
- I need both logical & physical. Most answers I saw only give one of the two

Comment: I don't have a Ubuntu on physical machine, right now to try `nproc`? https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/nproc.1.html

Comment: nproc gives one value. I need both values

Answer (score 3):

Physical cores:

```
egrep '^core id' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | wc -l
```

Logical cores:

```
egrep '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | wc -l
```

Physical cpus (separate chips):

```
egrep '^physical id' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: The cores number is wrong. sorting it with -u collapses all cores to 1

Comment: also, since u don't care about the sort, and just want to return unique values, u can use `| uniq` instead of `| sort -u` which makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

There is a package inxi.

```
sudo apt install inxi
```

Then try

```
inxi --cpu
```

Comment: Nice, but I'd rather use basic utils, such as `awk` & `lscpu` without needing to install new pkgs

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
```

0 based, so this machine has 56 logical cores.

```
processor       : 55
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz
```

Comment: see my comment to user.dz - I need both logical & phy